# Flutter - Target kernel_snapshot failed: ProcessException

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, dart

i have a flutter project with firebase db and auth with it. When im trying to build project or run project on emulator, i am getting this error:

```
Target kernel_snapshot failed: ProcessException: Dosya virüslü olduğundan veya istenmeyebilecek yazılım içerdiğinden işlem başarılı bir şekilde tamamlanmadı.

  Command: D:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --disable-dart-dev D:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\snapshots\frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root D:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --target=flutter --no-print-incremental-dependencies -Dflutter.inspector.structuredErrors=true -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --no-link-platform --packages D:\projeler\Flutter\Canny\.dart_tool\package_config.json --output-dill D:\projeler\Flutter\Canny\.dart_tool\flutter_build\d95b557b9d143169b0dead4fda0df2c0\app.dill --depfile D:\projeler\Flutter\Canny\.dart_tool\flutter_build\d95b557b9d143169b0dead4fda0df2c0\kernel_snapshot.d --incremental --initialize-from-dill D:\projeler\Flutter\Canny\.dart_tool\flutter_build\d95b557b9d143169b0dead4fda0df2c0\app.dill --source file:///D:/projeler/Flutter/Canny/.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart --source package:flutter/src/dart_plugin_registrant.dart -Dflutter.dart_plugin_registrant=file:///D:/projeler/Flutter/Canny/.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart --verbosity=error package:canny/main.dart


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 8s
```

Dosya virüslü olduğundan veya istenmeyebilecek yazılım içerdiğinden işlem başarılı bir şekilde tamamlanmadı : The operation did not complete successfully because the file is infected or contains potentially unwanted software

Before this error, it was giving error similar to
`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.`
and i have upgraded flutter with the line `flutter upgrade --force`. since then i am getting "Target kernel_snapshot failed: ProcessException:" error too.

Note: I have a teammate and we are developing project with using git. he doesnt getting these errors and he can build or run project successfully.

Note-2: I have already tried commands  `flutter doctor -v` , `gradlew build --stacktrace`

What should I do? please help me

Note-2: I have already tried commands  `flutter doctor -v` , `gradlew build --stacktrace`

flutter doctor -v result :

````
    • Flutter version 3.7.5 on channel stable at D:\src\flutter                                  
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git                                 
    • Framework revision c07f788888 (5 days ago), 2023-02-22 17:52:33 -0600                      
    • Engine revision 0f359063c4                                                                 
    • Dart version 2.19.2
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-TiramisuPrivacySandbox, build-tools 33.0.1
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: D:\ANDSTUD\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.9)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.11.32106.194
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0
    X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++" workload, and include these components:       
        MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
         - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
        C++ CMake tools for Windows
        Windows 10 SDK

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at D:\ANDSTUD
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2604]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 110.0.5481.177
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 110.0.1587.57

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.```
````

Comment: hi @alibk1 , please add result of `flutter doctor -v` on your question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import firebase core package in your file

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).